# Данные формы не отправляются в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Данные из формы не отправляются в MySQL датабазу. Вот код:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['token'])){

$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$phone = $_POST['phone']; 
$token = $_POST['token'];

$db_host = '';
$db_user = '';
$db_password = '';
$db_base = '';
$db_table = '';

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password, $db_base);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die('Ошибка : ('. $mysqli->connect_error .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (login,password,email,phone,token) VALUES ('$login','$password','$email','$phone','$token')");
if ($result == true){
echo "Информация занесена в базу данных";
}else{
echo "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
}
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

На выходе выдает "Информация не занесена в базу данных"

Comment: Теперь требуется открыть мануал http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php, найти как вывести текст ошибки, вывести его и осознать.

Comment: Благодарю. У меня не было опыта работы с PHP и MySQL до этого, и я взялся гуглить. Я почему-то думал что PHP сам создаст таблицу в выбранной базе данных если её нет :)

Comment: Попробуйте так:
$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (login,password,email,phone,token) VALUES ('{$login}','{$password}','{$email}','{$phone}','{$token}')");

Comment: Не, не создаст, откуда ж он узнает какие вам там поля нужны)

Comment: Кстати раз уж вы начинаете работать с php/mysql - то рекомендую сразу работать с __подготовленными выражениями__, это избавит вас от массы проблем.

Answer (score -1):

```
$db_host = '';
$db_user = '';
$db_password = '';
$db_base = '';
$db_table = '';
```

не только ето а и одиночные кавычки здесь

```
$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (login,password,email,phone,token) VALUES ('$login','$password','$email','$phone','$token')");
```

место етого надо

```
 $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (`login`,`password`,`email`,`phone`,`token`) VALUES (".$login.",".$password.",".$email.",".$phone.",".$token.")");
```

Comment: Подумали хоть бы чуть-чуть прежде чем писать. `INSERT INTO table (login) VALUES (Username)` - это по вашему верный запрос?

Comment: "место етого" не надо. Нет разницы между ' и ". В ответе был бы смысл если бы у меня было написано, к примеру, VALUES ('$login"). А так ответ, хоть и посредственный, но уже был дан

Comment: кавычки вабще переводят в тип string
но двойные позволяют читать значение переменных находящихся внутри кавычек а ' просто string